# "undefined reference" error compiling a static library in C

Tags: c, gcc

I have a file main.c, a header rippledp.h and a library rippledp.a. The problem is: when I execute the "make" command, I get this output:

```
g++ -O2 -DNDEBUG -static   -o rippledp main.o rippledp.a -lm -pthread
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `rippledp_read'
main.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `rippledp'
main.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `rippledp_write'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: ** [rippledp] Erro 1
```

Here is the Makefile:

```
#--------------------------------------------------#
#  Ripple-DP (ISPD2015 contest version)            #
#  Copyright (c) 2015                              #
#  Department of Computer Science and Engineering  #
#  The Chinese Univeristy of Hong Kong             #
#                                                  #
#  Contact:                                        #
#  Wing-Kai Chow <wkchow@cse.cuhk.edu.hk>          #
#  Evangeline F.Y. Young <fyyoung@cse.cuhk.edu.hk> #
#--------------------------------------------------#

OPT= -O2 -DNDEBUG
#OPT= -O0 -ggdb
TYPE= -static
#WFLAG= -Wall -Winline

CC= g++ $(OPT) $(TYPE) $(WFLAG) $(DEBUG)

LIBS= -lm -pthread

SRCS = ${OBJS:%.o=%.c}
BFILE = rippledp

all:    $(BFILE)

#$(BFILE): main.o rippledp.a libdef.a liblef.a
#   $(CC) -o $(BFILE) main.o rippledp.a libdef.a liblef.a $(LIBS)

$(BFILE): main.o rippledp.a
    $(CC) -o $(BFILE) main.o rippledp.a $(LIBS)

%.o : %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c $*.c


clean:
    rm -f *.o $(BFILE) core
```

Here is main.c:

```
#include "rippledp.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    /* read benchmark files: tech.lef, cells.lef, floorplan.def */
    /* read global placement solution: placed.def */
    rippledp_read((char*) "tech.lef", (char*) "cells.lef", (char*) "floorplan.def", (char*) "placed.def");

    /* detailed placement with target utility and maximum displacement constraint */
    rippledp(0.8, 200000);

    /* write the detailed placement solution to output file */
    rippledp_write((char*)"dplaced.def");

    return 0;
}
```

And here is rippledp.h:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Ripple-DP (ISPD2014 contest version)              */
/*  Copyright (c) 2014                              */
/*  Department of Computer Science and Engineering  */
/*  The Chinese Univeristy of Hong Kong             */
/*                                                  */
/*  Contact:                                        */
/*  Wing-Kai Chow <wkchow@cse.cuhk.edu.hk>          */
/*  Evangeline F.Y. Young <fyyoung@cse.cuhk.edu.hk> */
/*--------------------------------------------------*/

#ifndef _RIPPLEDP_H_
#define _RIPPLEDP_H_

/*read benchmarks and placed global placement solution*/
void rippledp_read(char *tech_file, char *cell_file, char *floorplan_file, char *placed_file);

/*Perform displacement-constrained legalization and detailed placement*/
/* target_util = target utility */
/* max_disp    = maximum displacement constraint */
void rippledp(double target_util, double max_disp);

/*write placement result in DEF format*/
void rippledp_write(char *output_file);

#endif
```

I also tried to compile and link manually. I first compiled using:

```
gcc -c main.c
```

Then, I tried all these alternatives for linking (I renamed rippledp.a to librippledp.a):

```
gcc -o out -L. -lrippledp main.o
gcc -o out -L. main.o -lrippledp 
gcc -o out main.o -L. -lrippledp 
gcc main.o -o out -L. -lrippledp 
gcc -o out -lrippledp -L. main.o
gcc -lrippledp -o out -L. main.o
```

and the output was the same.

I dont have access to the library content.

Comment: Does `nm` on the library actually show the symbols?

Comment: Are you sure you have `rippledp.h` that corresponds to `rippledp.a`? (try `nm`) Are you sure that `rippledp.a` has the right architecture? (try `objdump -a`). By the way `-lrippledp` **never** uses a file named `rippledp.a`, it can only use `librippledp.a` or `librippledp.so`.

Comment: If you use -lrippledp as an argument, doesn't it look for librippledp.a?  Does make me wonder if the "rippledp.a" has been built right if it's not named with that normal lib....a form.

Comment: Run a clean operation (remove the object files and libraries that you build) and rerun the build.  Record where it goes wrong, and what led up to the failure.  Note that C code cannot call C++ functions unless those functions were declared `extern "C"` in the C++ code.  That requires care — interworking between C and C++ requires care.

Answer (score 4):

[Your library](http://www.ispd.cc/contests/15/web/downloads.html) is compiled with C++ and thus contains C++ mangled names. But you compiled `main.c` as C, so it looked for unmangled names and thus couldn't find them. Rename `main.c` to `main.cpp` and compile it with g++ to fix this issue.

Comment: OK but why does the linker report unmangled function names? This should not normally happen in this situation. main.c seems to be compiled with gcc, g++ only does the linking.

Comment: @n.m. Names in error messages are demangled automatically. It would be quite annoying to decipher C++ errors otherwise.

Comment: @n.m. And the makefile defines `CC` to be `g++` so `main.c` is compiled with that.

Comment: When ld demangles a C++ function name, it includes the signature. Not happening here. The question actually mentions explicitly that main.c is compiled by gcc (not CC, not g++).

Comment: @n.m. The `%.o` rule in the makefile will use `g++`.

Comment: OP mentions that manual compilation with gcc without make was tried too.

Comment: @n.m. But OP says that after manual compilation he used `-lrippledb` to link. That wouldn't find the library because its name doesn't start with `lib`. The makefile specifies the library file directly which should work.

Comment: Yep I just commented on this, but lack of either mangling or signatures in ld messages is still incompatible with your theory.

Comment: @n.m. I [found the files OP is using](http://www.ispd.cc/contests/15/web/downloads.html) - see " C++ API to RippleDP". The problem is the reverse of what I said - the library contains mangled names and the linker looked for unmangled names (probably because OP used gcc before running make). A shame that OP refuses to answer comments or this would be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks, I think this worked. I say "I think" because I have other errors, but I think they have nothing to do with it. I am trying to solve them.